# Geometric consequences of the Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Studying geometric consequences of the Hahn-Banach Theorem, I stuck this problem :

> Let $M \subset X$, a TVS(topological vector space), and show that the following statements are equivalent :
>
> (a) $M$ is an affine hyperplane
>
> (b) there exists an $x_0$ in $M$ such that $M-x_0$ is a hyperplane
>
> (c) there is a non-zero linear function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{F} $ and an $\alpha$ in $ \mathbb{F}$ such that $M=\{x\in X:f(x)=\alpha \}. $

I can't start to prove this. Can someone help me?

Comment: Separating hyperplane theorem would probably help

Comment: Can you write down the  definition of a hyperplane? You should at least prove (a) iff (b) using the definition.